# Div height and link line break/wrapping

Tags: html, css

It's really difficult trying to explain what the issue is but if you look at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Relborg/Xfv6Y/) I created things will be a lot more cleaer.

Firstly you'll notice that the line heights of the rows aren't equal, even though the heights should be set to 33% thus all should be equally high.. This is sadly not the case..

And secondly, there's a longer link that should get wrapped inside it's own button, at the moment the button kind of gets cut off half way creating a broken look.

Again it was really difficult naming this post in regards to my particular issue. Having a look at the JSFiddle will makes things more clear.

```
//Ignore this comment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your Code and change your css.

```
Add float:left to #specialist-area-nav,#specialist-area-nav a,#specialist-area-nav .row, #specialist-area-nav .col;
Ad  margin-top:1% to #specialist-area-nav .row;
Change #specialist-area-nav a padding to 5px;
Add margin-left:1% to #specialist-area-nav .col;
Change #specialist-area-nav .row height to 32%;
Add white-space: nowrap to #specialist-area-nav a;
```

[JSFiddle Updated Source](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfv6Y/5/)

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the max percentage width that is defined, the buttons will get cut in half where white space is found. To get around this, add the following to your code:

```
#specialist-area-nav a{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will prevent the breaks of your buttons, and will keep them the same height.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xfv6Y/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `#specialist-area-nav a{ display:inline-block; }` will solve some problems, but then you'll still have some more tunning to do.